# Using mongodb with CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have been trying to use Mongodb with CodeIgniter 4 but facing issues.

puppyModel.php -

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
use App\Libraries\Mongo;

class puppyModel{
    /**
     * @var Mongo
     */
    protected $m;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->m = new Mongo();
    }

    public function getList(string $collection, array $where = [], array $options = [], array $select = [])
    {
        return $this->m->options($options)->select($select)->where($where)->find($collection)->toArray();
    }
}

?>
```

Home.php (Controller) -

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use app\Models\puppyModel;

class Home extends BaseController{
    public function index(){
        $puppyModel = new puppyModel();
        $data1 = $puppyModel->getList();
        print_r($data1);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error -

```
CRITICAL - 2022-02-02 23:58:05 --> Class "app\Models\puppyModel" not found
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cimongo\system\CodeIgniter.php(825): App\Controllers\Home->index()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\cimongo\system\CodeIgniter.php(412): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController(Object(App\Controllers\Home))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\cimongo\system\CodeIgniter.php(320): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(NULL, Object(Config\Cache), false)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\cimongo\index.php(37): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
#4 {main}
```

I am using this repo as a reference - https://github.com/bertugfahriozer/ci4mongodblibrary
I have already placed the config and library files as in the repo and changed namespaces.

Comment: Your `use app` in your controller should be `use App` - see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

**use app\Models\puppyModel" not found**

try this one

```
use App\Models\puppyModel
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your question. I'm sorry for the late reply.

I think it will work if you edit your file like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use ci4mongodblibrary\Libraries\Mongo;

class puppyModel{
```

i developing a cms/erp system with this repository. you can check from this link :

https://github.com/ci4-cms-erp